# Processos com Nodejs

Tags: node.js, lista, processo

gostaria de saber como faço pra pegar todos os processos com o nodejs igual ao c#

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
```

Gostaria de fazer isso em NODEJS, para retornar todos os PID do computador, não só do nodejs

Comment: Não há uma maneira nativa de fazer isso no Node. Dá uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33583340/2256325 enquanto não surge uma resposta aqui

Answer (score 0):

Sim, voce precisa usar process = require ('process'); Então

Para pegar o processo você precisa do process ID:

```
if (process.pid) {
  console.log('Este processo é seu pid' + process.pid);
}
```

Para pegar da plataforma:

```
console.log('Esta plataforma é ' + process.platform);
```

Atualize conforme seus requerimentos. (Teste WINDOWS)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var yourPID = '1444';

exec('tasklist', function(err, stdout, stderr) { 
    var lines = stdout.toString().split('\n');
    var results = new Array();
    lines.forEach(function(line) {
        var parts = line.split('=');
        parts.forEach(function(items){
        if(items.toString().indexOf(yourPID) > -1){
        console.log(items.toString().substring(0, items.toString().indexOf(yourPID)));
         }
        }) 
    });
});
```

No linux é algo assim:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    cmdd = spawn('your_command'); //something like: 'man ps'

cmdd.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('' + data);
});
cmdd.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
cmdd.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  if (/^execvp\(\)/.test(data)) {
    console.log('Failed to start child process.');
  }
});
```

[Retirado daqui!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471555/nodejs-process-info)

Answer (score -3):

Para listar todos os processos em execução no seu computador usando Node.js, você pode utilizar o mdulo **child_process** para executar comandos do sistema operacional que listam os processos. No Linux e macOS, o comando **ps**, segue o codigo abaixo comentado para entender cada part faz, **no exemplo estou utilizando no linux, nunca tentei listar processos no windows, mais e uma base forte para entender como funciona.**

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

// Executa o comando 'ps aux' para listar os processos
exec('ps aux', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    // Imprime uma mensagem de erro se houver um erro ao executar o comando
    console.error(`Erro ao executar o comando: ${error.message}`);
    return;
  }
  if (stderr) {
    // Imprime uma mensagem de erro se houver saída de erro do comando
    console.error(`Erro de saída: ${stderr}`);
    return;
  }
  // Divide a saída padrão do comando em linhas
  const lines = stdout.split('\n');
  // Itera sobre cada linha e exibe os detalhes do processo
  lines.forEach((line, index) => {
    if (index ===  0) {
      console.log(line); // Exibe o cabeçalho
    } else {
      const parts = line.trim().split(/\s+/);
      const pid = parts[0];
      const command = parts.slice(10).join(' ');
      // Exibe o PID e o comando do processo
      console.log(`PID: ${pid}, Comando: ${command}`);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).